# Help with an inductive proof of $(1+a)^n\ge 1+na$

Tags: proof-verification

Let $a$ be a fixed real number such that $a > -1$.
Prove $(1+a)^n \geq 1+an$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Base case.
$n = 1$.

$(1+a)^1 = 1+a(1)$

$\implies 1+a = 1+a$.

$1+a = 1+a(1)$.

so we can assume $P(n)$ is true when $n = 1$.

Want to show $P(n+1)$ holds.

$(1+a)^n = 1+an$

$(1+a)^n(1+a) = (1+an)(1+a)$

$(1+a)^{n+1} = 1+a+an+a^2n$

Notice $a^2n \geq 0$ since for $a > -1, a^2 > 0$.

$(1+a)^{n+1} \geq 1+a+an$

$(1+a)^{n+1} \geq 1+a(n+1)$.

so $P(n+1)$ holds.

Can someone scrutinize my base case? If I use $n=1$, how can I show that it's greater than or equal to, since the base case is just equal?

Comment: $a=b$ implies $a\geq b$

Comment: @symplectomorphic is correct. All you need to prove is that your statement is true for the base case, you don't need to (and can't) prove that it is both greater AND equal.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your responses.

Comment: @rb612: I'd be interested to see anyone prove that one number is both "greater AND equal" to another.

Comment: @symplectomorphic LOL, that was what I meant. You can't do so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $A=B$, you know that $A \le B$ and $A \ge B$.
In fact, $(A = B) \iff (A \le B) \land (A \ge B)$
Therefore, your base case becomes:
$n = 1$.

$(1+a)^1 = 1+a(1) = 1+a$
$\implies(1+a)^1 \ge 1+a(1)$
$\therefore P(1)$ holds

For the rest of the proof:

$(1+a)^n \ge 1+an$
$\implies (1+a)^n(1+a)\ge (1+an)(1+a)$
$= 1+an + a + a^2n$
$= 1+a(n+1)+a^2n$

$a^2 \ge 0, \forall a \in \Bbb{R}$
$\therefore 1+a(n+1)+a^2n \ge 1+a(n+1), \forall a\in \Bbb{R}, \forall n \ge 0$
$\therefore P(1) \land (P(n) \implies P(n+1))$

$\therefore P(n), \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Oh I get it so that's where the thing about that little $a^2k$ part being positive comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

The case $n=1$ has already been addressed in the comments.

A couple of further issues in your work:

1. It is not true that if $a>-1$, the $a^2>0$. In fact, $0>-1$. However, $a^2n\ge0$ holds regardless of any hypothesis stronger than, say, $n\in\Bbb N$ and $a\in \Bbb R$ (and "$a^2n\ge0$" is sufficient for the purpose of the proof). The point where you use $a>-1$ is just in the the implication $$(1+a)^n\ge 1+na\implies (1+a)^{n+1}\ge(1+a)(1+na)$$
2. ... which leads us to your second imprecision: the inductive step that you must prove is $$\forall n\ge1,\ \left[(1+a)^n\ge1+na\longrightarrow (1+a)^{n+1}\ge 1+(n+1)a\right]$$ while, formally, you proved the *weaker* predicate $$\forall n\ge1,\ \left[(1+a)^n=1+na\longrightarrow (1+a)^{n+1}\ge 1+(n+1)a\right]$$ The algebra is the same as you did, though, just with the "$\ge$" sign instead of "$=$".